# HTML5 - Pattern attribute can't be used in input element

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I'm currently having an input element for a phone number and trying to use the pattern attribute but it refuses to do so. it says "Validation(HTML5): **Pattern is not a valid attribute of element input"!** When I change the type to "text" it says that **pattern attribute is only valid when title is present!**

```
<input type="number" class="form-control"data-require="" id="Mobile" placeholder="Mobile No" autocomplete="off" pattern="[\+]\d{3}d{9}" required>
```

**UPDATE:**

I Added title attribute and it's working now! but my only issue is that when i click submit, it submits the form even though that the format is not matching.

Comment: Well did you try to add title attribute?

Comment: i updated my question, please check

Comment: For your example: `[\+]\d{3}d{9}` did you mean `d` or `\d`? Also, if the `type` is number, what's the goal here? To ensure the length? And why not just have `\d{12}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<input>` should be valid without the `title` attribute (validated on https://validator.nu/):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-require="" id="Mobile" placeholder="Mobile No" autocomplete="off" pattern="[\+]\d{3}d{9}" required>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Additional changes:**

- A space is missing before attribute `data-require`.
- The `pattern` attribute is only allowed on the following types: `email`, `password`, `search`, `tel`, `text`, or `url`.

Your regular expression (`[\+]\d{3}d{9}`) is also invalid. You can try one of the following rules:

- `[\+]\d{3}\d{9}`
- `[\+]\d{12}`

You are missing the `\` before the second `d` to match only numbers. The second pattern is a minified version of the first pattern.

Comment: the pattern i wrote is for the number to be in the format : +997566666666. can't this be used internationally?

Comment: you know you miss the \ on the second d

Comment: @SebastianBrosch - not to mention that if it should be `\d` it simply checks that it's 12 digits long.

Comment: Since you are using an input of type `number`, you could also just set the min value to `100000000000` and the max value to `999999999999` to ensure it is 12 digits long.

Comment: And the `+` character?

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed, just added this in my javascript.

/[+]\d{3}d{9}/.test(PhoneNo)

Answer (score -1):

You can add oninvalid attribute to the tag

`<input type="text" name="HasAPattern" pattern="\w{3}" title="Enter 3 characters" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Needs to match patern')" >`

The HTMLSelectElement.setCustomValidity() method sets the custom validity message for the selection element to the specified message. Use the empty string to indicate that the element does not have a custom validity error.

You can also use code like `event.preventDefault();` inside it to cancel the submit if invalid